# How to use df.column.str.contains() to get the same result as the code below?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to get the same result as the code below by using str.contains(), but I just couldn't get the same result.

The goal is to filter the column "question" of Dataframe "data" with the values that have both 'England' and 'King'.

```
def filter_data(data, words):
  filter = lambda x: all(word.lower() in x.lower() for word in words)
  return data.loc[data["question"].apply(filter)]

answer = filter_data(data, ['England', 'King'])
```

My code:

```
re_filter = data[
                (data.question.str.contains("(\w|\W)England(\w|\W)", regex= True, case= False))& 
                (data.question.str.contains("(\w|\W)King(\w|\W)", regex= True, case= False))
                ]
```

Was it because the wrong regex?
Thanks so much for all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

This it the easiest way:

```
data[data.question.str.contains(r'(?=.*England)(?=.*King)', case=False)]
```

With `case=False` it is case insensitive

Comment: hey gtomer, thanks for the help! I've tried your code but it only came up with 49 results, and it didn't find the words like viking as the sample solution did. 

Another question, the default regex= True in str.contains(), is it better to use r'(?=.*England)(?=.*King)' ?

Comment: I have added case=False to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'question':['I have both England and King', 'I have just England', 'I have just King']})
print(df[df.question.str.contains('England') & (df.question.str.contains('King'))])
```

Output:

```
                       question
0  I have both England and King
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Muhammad Hassan! After slight edit, I finally got all 152 correct results! Thanks so much!
    <pre>
    result = data[data.question.str.contains('England', case= False) &   (data.question.str.contains('King', case= False))]
    <code>